# passing values from controller to filter

Tags: java, spring

I like to pass values from a spring controller to a filter without using session. suggestions please..

From the first controller I set the values to the request and showing a page. Some jsp pages included with this view (using tiles) is using this attributes. When I try to access this values from this controllers, it is null .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add an attribute to the request in your controller (using `request.setAttribute(...)`), then fetch it in the filter (using `getAttribute(...)`).

(Answer is as lacking in detail as the question...)

Comment: this attributes are available only the immediate controller or jsp right? What if I want to access it from a controller which is called from a tiled (apache tiles) jsp.